# Unrecognized static methods - does the order matter?

Tags: php, oop, methods, static-methods, require-once

I have the error

`Call to undefined method Exception::message()`

inside the object calling

```
Utils::message()
```

(I am catching the Exception and replacing by the message)

The file containing this object is included (`require_once`) by the top file together with another file defining `Utils`.

So my question is why the method of `Utils` is not recognized. All classes are included before the main code. Does the inclusion order matter? Any other hints?

EDIT. My `Utils` class:

```
class Utils {

   private static $count;
   private static $aggregateCount, $time, $last, $previous;

 ...

  public static function message () {
      echo "\n Count: ", self::$count++, " ";
     $array = func_get_args();
     foreach ($array as $entry) {
       if (is_array($entry)) {
         echo print_r($entry);
       } else {
         echo $entry;         
       }
     }
  }

 ...
}
```

And here is the function using the class:

```
  public function updateManyWithId ($schema, array $bundle) {
    foreach ($bundle as $hash) {
      $id = $hash[ID_KEY];
      $hash = $this->_adjustId($schema, $hash);
      try {
        $this->update($schema, $id, $hash);
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        Utils::message("Cannot update hash: ", $hash, $e->message());
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Show more related code, please. But it seems like you're using the `$this` pointer when `$this` refers to the `Exception` you threw, and not `Utils`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$e->message()` Is the problem. That refers to a class called `Exception` which is expected to have a method called `message`, but your `Exception` class does not have that method.

Look at the constructor of your `Exception`. You're passing in a message when you throw it, perhaps you're looking for `$e->getMessage()`.

Read here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.getmessage.php

To summarize, consider this:

```
class Exception {
  //construct is used when you throw new Exception (instantiate the class)
  public function __construct($message) {
    $this->message = $message; //now the object has a "message" property
  }
  //this is a "getter" for this object's message
  public function getMessage() {
    return $this->message; //return the message
  }
}
```

Note that the standard usage of `getters/setters` is to use `getProperty` and `setProperty` as the method name that returns/sets that property.

Comment: Thanks, I now reduced the class to that function and included the calling function.

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev No problem! By the way, static methods can be dangerous because you are using `Utils` explicity rather than using Dependency Injection. When creating the class that uses `Utils` you should use Dependency Injection like this: `$myObj = new myObj(new Utils())` and then in `myObj`'s constructor, set `$this->Utils = $Utils`. Then in your function: `$this->Utils->message(..etc)` There are a lot of reasons that this is the best practice - study Dependency Injection for more info!

Comment: Thanks again, yes, I do indeed use dep. injection everywhere except for this class :) I had hard time to make this decision but the reasons is `Utils::message()` is more readable than `$this->utils->message()`, the latter is too easy to confuse with `$this->otherObject->otherMethod`, so this is a way to improve readability. Yes, doesn't make my test beautiful but the code looks nicer. Don't really know what is the best